# OpenTelemetry SDK Cardinality limit change

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, newrelic, open-telemetry

I set up a configuration for openTelemtry in Spring Boot (New Relic exporter). I can see the metrics in New Relic so everything works fine. Also I see a lot of warnings about "Cardinality Limit (2000)". By default cardinality is set to 2000. I'm not sure how can I change it. I can see in optl docs something like this:

> aggregation_cardinality_limit: A positive integer value defining the maximum number of data points allowed to be emitted in a collection cycle by a single instrument. See cardinality limits, below.

Link: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/metrics/sdk/#stream-configuration

My code:

```
 @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public OpenTelemetry openTelemetry() {
        return OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
            .setMeterProvider(
                SdkMeterProvider.builder()
                    .setResource(
                        Resource.getDefault().toBuilder()
                            .put("service.name", getAppName())
                            .put("instrumentation.provider", "micrometer")
                            .build())
                    .registerMetricReader(
                        PeriodicMetricReader.builder(
                                OtlpGrpcMetricExporter.builder()
                                    .setCompression("gzip")
                                    .setEndpoint(properties.getEndpoint())
                                    .addHeader("api-key", getLicenceKey())
                                    .setAggregationTemporalitySelector(AggregationTemporalitySelector.deltaPreferred())
                                    .setDefaultAggregationSelector(
                                        DefaultAggregationSelector.getDefault()
                                            .with(InstrumentType.HISTOGRAM, Aggregation.base2ExponentialBucketHistogram()))
                                    .build())
                            .setInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(properties.getInterval()))
                            .build())
                    .build())
            .build();
    }
```

I'm not sure if I can just pass another "                       .put("aggregation_cardinality_limit", 3000)" to Resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring cardinality limits is still experimental, so the APIs you call to set the limits are internal and leave a lot to be desired in terms of ergonomics. This will change when the limits are marked as stable in the specification.

You need to use [SdkMeterProviderUtil#registerMetricReaderWithCardinalitySelect](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/c57ca65f7f1455e2f9d72f3d2d626aaf2f2f9a81/sdk/metrics/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/sdk/metrics/internal/SdkMeterProviderUtil.java#L53-L67), something like:

```
SdkMeterProviderBuilder meterProviderBuilder = SdkMeterProvider.builder();
PeriodicMetricReader periodicMetricReader = PeriodicMetricReader.builder()
  // configuration omitted for brevity
  .build();
SdkMeterProviderUtil.registerMetricReaderWithCardinalitySelector(meterProviderBuilder, periodicMetricReader, unused -> 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way to change cardinality limit? (not experimental).  2000 looks like not enough for me. I don't know why default value is so small. I have metric with 4 tags (event, platform, app, region) and I get a lot of warns about "Instrument app.events has exceeded the maximum allowed cardinality (1999)."

Comment: The only other option is to use register the limit with a view, which allows you to target a narrower set of instruments than the reader, but that's experimental as well: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk/metrics/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/sdk/metrics/internal/SdkMeterProviderUtil.java#L113-L121 There are currently no options that aren't experimental. We're waiting for the specification to stabilize before we stabilize.